# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema  al momento de recibir el `json` me dice este error:

> **SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.**

Aquí esta mi código.

En esta parte tengo mi código de `php` con el que hago la consulta a la base de datos y retornarla al archivo `javascript` como formato `json`.

edita_usuario.php:

```
<?php  
 //fetch.php  
 include_once '../conexion.php'; 
 if(isset($_POST["id_user"]))  
 {   


    $Query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = '".$_POST["id_user"]."'";
    $sql = $conn->prepare($Query);
    $sql->execute();
    if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($rows = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $datos[] = $rows;
        }
        echo json_encode($datos);die;
    }
}
 ?>
```

En esta función envío el ***id_user*** lo cual si funciona correctamente, el problema viene cuando intenta recibir el `json`.
ajax:

```
function editUser(id_user) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "model/usuario/edita_usuario.php",
        data: { id: id_user },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            console.log(id_user);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#nombre').val(data.nombre);
            $('#apellidop').val(data.apellidop);
            $('#apellidom').val(data.apellidom);
            $('#contrasena').val(data.contrasena);
            $('#id_rol').val(data.id_rol);
            $('#nombre_usuario').val(data.username);
            $('#status').val(data.status);
            $('#modalForm').modal('show');

        }

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown, textStatus, jqXHR);
    });
}
```

Comment: Cambia esta línea: `echo json_encode($datos);die;` por esto: `echo json_encode($datos);` No necesitas usar `die`. Prueba y nos cuentas qué pasa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `die` sobra en tu código.

Además deberías:

- devolver algo si no hay datos, para controlarlo en el cliente.
- usar bien las consultas preparadas, sino tu código queda vulnerable

Intenta así:

#### Servidor

```
include_once '../conexion.php';
$mUser=!empty($_POST["id_user"]) ? $_POST["id_user"] : NULL;
$datos=array();
if($mUser)
{
    $Query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = ?";
    if ( $sql = $conn->prepare($Query) ) {
        $mArgs=array($mUser);
        $sql->execute($mArgs);
        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($rows = $sql ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $datos[] = $rows;
            }
        } else {
            $datos['error']= 'No hay filas encontradas';
        }
    } else {
        $datos['error']= 'No se preparó la consulta. Error: '.$conn->errorInfo()[2];
    }
} else {
    $datos['error']= 'No se posteó un id_user';

}

echo json_encode($datos);
```

#### Cliente

Dentro del `success` verificas primero si no hay una clave `error` en la respuesta, pasando a mostrar los datos.

```
function editUser(id_user) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "model/usuario/edita_usuario.php",
        data: { id: id_user },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            console.log(id_user);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.error) {
                alert (data.error); //Esto lo puedes poner en un elemento HTML si quieres
            } else {
                $('#nombre').val(data.nombre);
                $('#apellidop').val(data.apellidop);
                $('#apellidom').val(data.apellidom);
                $('#contrasena').val(data.contrasena);
                $('#id_rol').val(data.id_rol);
                $('#nombre_usuario').val(data.username);
                $('#status').val(data.status);
                $('#modalForm').modal('show');
            }
        }

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown, textStatus, jqXHR);
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo si me funciono!